# How much fullness does combat drain?

Tags: neo-the-world-ends-with-you

In *NEO: TWEWY*, ordering food raises a fullness bar. If the bar goes past 100%, you can't order more food until you drain your fullness to 0% by battling noise.

How much fullness gets drained by combat? Is the amount of fullness drained affected by things like the length of a fight or difficulty level? Or is it a consistent amount per fight?